# Horizontal scrollbar when a Rally cardboard is used inside an Ext Tab

Tags: rally

I have a Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard as an item in an Ext.tab.Panel. When there are enough cards to cause a vertical scrollbar to appear, eating 16px of width, instead of fitting the new width dynamically, a horizontal scrollbar appears too. This doesn't happen when the CardBoard is rendered to document.body.

I've been looking for the right set of config options to make the TabPanel and its child items[] resize automatically. After two days trying in vain, I'm about to give up and just force a width of 1902px for PCs and 2862px for Macs. If anyone has a better idea, I'm more than willing to try it... anything at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could find no way to do this through config options alone, so we ended up listening to the App's own `resize` event and updated the panel size. In the App config we have this, and it does the trick:

```
listeners: {
    resize: function( app, width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight, eOpts ) {
        if (app.TabPanel) {
            app.TabPanel.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
            app.TabPanel.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has a better solution that only uses config options and the framework does the resizing, I'd still like to see it, as the above is an ugly hack even if it works.